# Multiple images in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a  `UIScrollView` at my view. And also have an array which have images now i want to display that images in the scrollview. i am new in `iPhone` if someone help me. i will be very gald.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d.png",b, i]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    [images addObject:img];
    NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
    imge.image=img;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need to set [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html) of your `UIScrollView`; 
And add Your `UIImageView` to your ScrollView, such like

```
[self.myScView addSubView:self.imageView];
```

And you need to add **image** on separate `UIImageView`;
Read This basic of [UIScrollView](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/)

I just want to put my Logic here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 465);
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    int Y = 0;

   // here give you image name is proper so we can access it by for loop.
    for (int i = 1; i <=  totalNumberOFImage; i++)
    {
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, Y, 100, 100)] ;
      [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youImageName%d", i]]];
      [self.scrollView addSubview: imageView];
      Y = Y + imageView.frame.size.height+5;

     if(y > 465)
      self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y);
    }
}
```

Follow this code may be it helps in your case:

Comment: can you send me a comprehensive solution.

Comment: follow my answer .. :)

Comment: what is imgLogo here.

Comment: sory its my mistake , add your ImageView name here.. i edited my answer